# Request doesn't end when using AJAX uploading and delete the upload file

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I can't give my full source code because of the copyright but I'll describe the problem in detail.

I uses AJAX uploading to upload a file. Everything is ok except that when I `choose a file, delete it outside then submit it`, the request doesn't end. The problem happens on Firefox. This is the figure:

[image]

```
public function inputAction()
{
    // Get request.
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    if($request->getMethod() == "POST" && $request->request->has("uploadFile")) {
        var_dump("It should output this"); exit();

        // In practice, It will run to this.
        $request->request->set("finish", true);
    }

    // Set this to close loading dialog.
    $request->request->set("finish", false);

    // Render view.
    return $this->render('frontendfrontBundle:Convert:input.html.php', array("bag" => $request->request));
}
```

My form

```
            <form id="convertForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('Convert_input');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">

            <!-- Used for file uploading -->
            <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe> 

            <input id="uploadFile" type="file" class="width_txt" name="uploadFile"/>

            </form>

    <?php
        if($bag->get("finish", false) == true) {
    ?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                window.parent.stopUpload();                 
            });                  
        </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

JAvascript

```
$("#convertForm").submit(function(e) { // onSubmit()
        startUpload();
});
```

Comment: Is it better if you comment the line with var_dump and exit ?

Comment: As far as I can see you're always setting finish to false... even when setting it to true in the if it will get set to false after existing the if clause.

Comment: No, it's not the problem. This is my demo for that >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654595/ajax-uploading-hangs-out-after-deleting-the-file-outside-firefox-pros-come-he